# Create uniqueID based on id mysql laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create uniqueID for column **transid** like autoincrement.  but I already have a column **id** (autoincrement).

column **transid** should be 01000001 and autoincrement, or follow column **id**  number.

here is my code

```
public function insertFund($request,$lender, $ftype, $sign)
{
    $fmamt = str_replace(".","",$request->fmamt );
    $fdesc = $request->fdesc;
    $fdate = $request->fdate;
    $trnsfer  = $request->file('upload_trnsfer');         
    $transid = "01".str_pad($fund->id, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 

    if($fdesc == null)
    {
        $fdesc = '';
    }
    $fund = $this->fund->create([
        'lender_id' => $lender->id,
        'transid' => $transid,
        'fmamt' => $fmamt,
        'refdc' => '',
        'ftype' => $ftype,
        'sign'  => $sign,
        'fdesc' => $fdesc,
        'fdate' => $fdate,
        'fstat' => 'pending'
    ]);
    return $fund;
}
```

I think, the core issue is here.

```
$transid = "01".str_pad($fund->id, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

How should I write code in for this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: $transid = "01".str_pad($fund->id, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);  in this code write  echo $fund->id ; see what u got??

Comment: i think u try to insert id n transid at the same time,then how can u will get $fund->id  ...before insert somevalue then get the last inserted id n then add transid ...i think its the bettr way

Comment: I know I'm try to insert id and transid at the same time, and actually this is my problem.  if I get the last inserted id, last number of tansid will be different with id right? ...... I dont wanna do that, I want that last number of transid has the same number with id.

Comment: no, transid n id will be same ,what u have to do is that first insert all data along with transid...then immediately get the last id of insert ,then update only transid or first insert all data except  transid...then get the last id of insert ,then update only transid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Hope this help you

```
$temp_str = '00000000';
```

Last inserted id

```
$obj_fund = Fund::get()->last();
$last_inserted_id = $obj_fund->id;

$temp_index = $last_inserted_id + 1;    
$id_length = strlen($temp_index);
$temp_id = substr_replace($temp_str, $last_inserted_id, -$id_length);
```

Your get 00000012

Comment: it will be the same id 00000012 in every submit. I want to be autoincrement.

Comment: Yes, You need to take last inserted id from database, 12 is just example

Comment: hmm I'm sorry, can you give me an example? coz I dont know how to change 12 become last insert id

Comment: Just take last inserted record id, nw I edited my ans, Fund is a Model name.

Comment: wow it works great! . but last number is use last id.. hmm how if use the same id?

Comment: oh, just + 1 like this : $last_inserted_id = $obj_fund->id + 1;

Comment: Thank you Komal you help me twice! :)